# Java - call object method on a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading

fairly new to Java and multithreading problems so pls bear with me.

**Question**: Is it possible to create multiple threads and "assign" a certain method to one thread (I was hoping for a nice decorator of some sort) so that whenever the method is called, its called on the designated thread rather than the main thread? (Hope that makes sense).

**Background**: I am working on an event handler object which will receive a request and return a certain action to the caller (through "method A"). The event handler will then receive several separate responses to the action, each of which will trigger "method B". The handler should wait for a response that is "terminal" and only then should it allow another request to come in. So I would like to block any incoming requests until I receive a terminal state on a response to the request that is currently being handled.

**Approach so far**: I have tried using a CountDownLatch but the problem is that when I block the main thread in method A after receiving a request, method B does not get called at all because it is called on the same thread I assume.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try ForkJoinPools? https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join

Comment: So you have two `public void actionX()` methods you wish to serialize access to?

Comment: Yes, except they are not void; they return a map.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do what you want to do. Slightly different from the way you expected, but you will need to read a bit on that. The class that you need is [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). Also, look at the class [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call a method in an async way then Spring Async is a pretty good option, you can pass in custom thread pool to control concurrency

If you want to write it using JDK only then

A. Create ThreadPool

```
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

B. Wrap logic in your method in [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

C. create ExecutorCompletionService and listen using [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html)

```
executorCompletionService.submit(callable) // submit tasks to ExecuterService
val taskExecutionResult = executorCompletionService.take().get();
```

Comment: So on B.: the method is part of an interface and will/should always be called directly by the user/caller. So once wrapped into callable, how is that possible?

Comment: sorry not understood question, but what I meant to say about callable is ExecutorCompletionService.submit will take only callable/runnable as an argument

Comment: ExecutorCompletionService will help you take result back from ExecutorService